# I need to add a conditional statement to link css height to pulldown selection (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this in my code, currently:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$( "#grow" ).click(function(){
    $( "#background" ).animate( { height: "800" })
});

$( "#shrink" ).click(function(){
    $( "#background" ).animate({ height: "585" });
});
```

it grows or shrinks the background containor and keeps the bottom css right below the main form. However, I need to add to the height accomodate a pulldown menu with both a hidden field and the associated error message (or contract it if they choose another pulldown selection).

any ideas on how I should do this? My pulldown's ID is: ddlFeedbackType, there's an onChange event handler called onchange="ShowHidePageURL()" and here's the hide/show script:

```
var x;
var o = document.getElementById ('plc_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder_pageplaceholder_lt_zoneCenter_ASME_FormsSuggestionForm_ddlFeedbackType');
if (o.options[o.selectedIndex].text == "Report a Bug") {
    x = document.getElementById('divPageURLlabel');
    x.style.display = "block";

    x = document.getElementById('divPageURLtext');
    x.style.display = "block";

    x = document.getElementById('divFeedbackType');
    x.style.display = "none";

    x = document.getElementById('lblFeedbackType');
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

I just don't know how to put it all together, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: does '#background' contain only the  main form?

Answer (score 0):

assuming the following HTML structure

```
<div id="#background">
   <form id="form">
      ....
   </form>
</div>
```

you should style it like:

```
#background{height:585px;overflow:hidden;}
```

then in your javascript:

```
$( "#grow" ).click(function(){
    if(test your pulldown value){
       $('<controls to hide>').hide();
    } else {
       $('<controls to show>').show();
    }

    $( "#background" ).animate( { height: $('form').height() })
});

$( "#shrink" ).click(function(){
    $( "#background" ).animate({ height: "585" });
});
```

This way, the #background will always animate to the height of the form, so if the controls are hidden, the height will accomodate.

Comment: Actually, here's a link to my test page, as you can see it's not working all that well...http://sandbox.asme.org/about-asme/suggestion-form...i'm sorry, i don't know that much jquery and so don't know how to apply what you showed me. The developer did all the error handling, etc, i was just supposed to get some jQuery solution to work. I have to try and fix it.

Comment: i'm trying to implement the code again, and when i tried to use overflow:hidden; it hid part of my graphic in the form...moving on to the rest of the code...